# SQL Server silent installation does not work

Tags: sql-server, installation, silent

We need to install SQL Server Express 2008 silently without any user interaction.

I am using this code but in the middle of the installation the user interface comes out

```
   SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe /q /ACTION=INSTALL /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /INSTANCEID=SQLEXPRESS /SQLSVCACCOUNT="DESKTOP-3PD9O0B\Abdalrhman" /SQLSVCPASSWORD="" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="DESKTOP-3PD9O0B\Abdalrhman" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="DESKTOP-3PD9O0B\Abdalrhman" /AGTSVCPASSWORD="" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

[image]

Please any help

Comment: SQL2008 was end-of-lifed in 2019, any reason you still want to use it?

Comment: This question is not related to programming / code. Consider asking it on Database Administrators ([dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), you  can use the same account).

Comment: That looks like Windows 10 or Windows Server equivalent. Unless I recall incorrectly, neither will run such an old version of SQL Server

Comment: what the problem in SQL2008 , i have multi customer working on them and i can't upgrade all customer